# How to add existing local device to Genymotion

Tags: android, genymotion

I have just reinstalled Windows and then Genymotion.
How to add existing virtual devices to Genymotion lists?
I change the default virtual divice path to the previous one (in `D:/VM`, there are 2 installed devices here), but Genymotion doesn't "rescan" my previous installed devices?

I don't want to delete these devices and add them again.
[image]

Comment: Do you have .ova file for virtual device?

Comment: I think I do not have: http://i.imgur.com/SL1Ajhh.png

Comment: Just double click on that device and import, then it will displayed in your genymotion screen

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, if you have previously downloaded some devices for Genymotion and now you want to add them to a new installation, you should :

1. find the `.ova` file of the virtual device

   > If you have a previous installation of Genymotion, it is located in:
   >   `%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion`
2. Double click on the device and use VirtualBox to import the .ova file.

Genymotion will recognize the device automatically.